# Array not looping correctly Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple fact app that has an array of different facts.
I have a next, previous, and home button.
When the home button is pressed, I want the first fact to be displayed again, and after, it will start incrementing again from the first array value.

My home button is not working. If I hit the next button 5 times, then hit the home button, I will be directed to the first fact, but if I hit the next button, then the 6th fact will display, not the second.

Here is my code:

```
public String nextFact() {
        i++;
        if(i >= facts.length) {
            i = 0;
        }

        return facts[i];
    }


    public String previousFact() {
        i--;
        if(i < 0) {
            i = facts.length - 1;
        }
        return facts[i];
    }

    public String homeButton() {
        int i = 0;
        return facts[i];
    }
```

Comment: Where is `i` coming from? If it's part of the class, use `this.i`. Otherwise, pass as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring a new  *local* version of `i`.
It should be:

```
public String homeButton() {
        i = 0;
        return facts[i];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your code, I am assuming i is a variable shared across the three methods, which keeps track of the index of the question currently displayed. If that is the case, your method should reset the class member i to 0, instead of creating a local variable.

```
public String homeButton() {
    i = 0;
    return facts[i];
}
```

This should do the trick.